# Why in Flutter, when I go to another page, the text in TextField disappears?

Tags: flutter, dart

I enter text in `TextField`. When I click a button to go to another page and back, the text in the `TextField` disappears. Has anyone encountered this problem and can give me some advice?

My code:

```
Column(
  children: [
    ListTile(
      onTap: () async {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => …)); // In fact, I used go_router, just replaced it with the Navigator that everyone should know
      },
      leading: const Icon(Icons.location_pin, color: Colors.black),
      title: Text("Location"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: const Icon(Icons.message, color: Colors.black),
      title: TextFormField(
        controller: messageController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: "Message",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

Why in Flutter, when I go to another page, the text in `TextField` disappears? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: does the messageController initialisation in somewhere else than initState ?

Comment: @Gwhyyy `messageController` is not initialized elsewhere (including `initState` is not initialized either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you create the `TextEditingController` when you navigate to this page so it will be created with empty text.
So you can make the controller global not inside `StatefulWidget`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchScrean extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScrean({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchScrean> createState() => _SearchScreanState();
}

class _SearchScreanState extends State<SearchScrean> {
  // you probably initialize the controller here or in initState.
  TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController(); 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        TextFormField(
          controller: messageController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: "Message",
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

See the comment.
You have to initialize it outside like this or use a state management package like `bloc` or `provider` :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// initialize it here or in another global file
TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController(); 

class SearchScrean extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScrean({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchScrean> createState() => _SearchScreanState();
}

class _SearchScreanState extends State<SearchScrean> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        TextFormField(
          controller: messageController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: "Message",
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

and when you don't want it anymore dispose it using `messageController.dispose()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Can you share some code?

Comment: I have share an example code.